# Shopify-Bulk query to get all the products details

Tags: graphql, shopify

I have a requirement of getting all the products details(i want every detail like id,body,title,vendor,body_html,product_type etc of the each product) from a particular shop in shopify .I want to get same data as we get in ('/products.json?limit=250') Admin API request .I wanted to use bulk query to solve this.i have gone through the shopify Admin GraphQl API Docs. I was not able to find a query which will give all the product details in the shop.

I have tried below query.

```
query = '''
    mutation {
        bulkOperationRunQuery(
        query : """
            {
                products {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            id
                            title
                            vendor
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        """
        ){
        bulkOperation {
                id
                status
        }
        userErrors {
            field
            message
        }
    }
}'''
shopify.GraphQL().execute(query)
```

the above query is executing properly. I am getting the below success response.

'{"data":{"bulkOperationRunQuery":{"bulkOperation":{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/BulkOperation\/2061234200041","status":"CREATED"},"userErrors":[]}},"extensions":{"cost":{"requestedQueryCost":10,"actualQueryCost":10,"throttleStatus":{"maximumAvailable":1000.0,"currentlyAvailable":990,"restoreRate":50.0}}}}'

but when i add extra field like product_type then it throwing me an error.

```
query = '''
    mutation {
        bulkOperationRunQuery(
        query : """
            {
                products {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            id
                            title
                            vendor
                            product_type
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        """
        ){
        bulkOperation {
                id
                status
        }
        userErrors {
            field
            message
        }
    }
}'''
#print(query)
shopify.GraphQL().execute(query)
```

output:

'{"data":{"bulkOperationRunQuery":{"bulkOperation":null,"userErrors":[{"field":["query"],"message":"**Invalid bulk query**: Field 'product_type' doesn't exist on type 'Product'"}]}},"extensions":{"cost":{"requestedQueryCost":10,"actualQueryCost":10,"throttleStatus":{"maximumAvailable":1000.0,"currentlyAvailable":990,"restoreRate":50.0}}}}'

As anyone used bulk query to get all the products details from shopify for particular store? if yes , would you help me by posting the query here.

Comment: You will need to specify everything that you want to get as a response, there is no option that will return to you every field that the product has. you will need to do that through GraphQL by specifying what everything you want. That's how GraphQL works

Comment: in the  query, i have added body_html, product_type ,created_at, product_type, updated_at,  published_at, template_suffix, admin_graphql_api_id in the query, it is throwing me an error while executing for these fields

Comment: You have error message Field 'product_type' doesn't exist on type 'Product'"

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple mistake. You slipped into the coma world of snake case versus camel case. Our overlords of JS love that.

In GraphQL world, it would be productType, not product_type.

Why we waste billions of dollars on broken software often boils down to these things. Yay!